# Django Inactivity Middleware not automatically logging user out

Tags: html, css, django, middleware

After a 10 minute inactivity interval, I want to log my django user out and update a backend value. However, it is only working when I reload my page or send some sort of request to the server after the 10 minute time interval.

Here is my current middleware code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from codera_main.models import UserDetail

class InactivityMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Check if the user is authenticated
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Check if the session has expired
            if request.session.get_expiry_age() <= 0:
                # Log out the user and consider them inactive
                user_detail = UserDetail.objects.get(user=request.user)
                if user_detail.isCurrentlyActive:
                    user_detail.isCurrentlyActive = False
                    user_detail.save()
                    print(f"User {user_detail.user} is now inactive and logged out.")
                logout(request)
                
            else:
                # Retrieve the last activity timestamp from the session
                last_activity = request.session.get('last_activity')

                # Check if the last activity timestamp exists and is valid
                if last_activity:
                    last_activity = datetime.fromisoformat(last_activity)
                    time_since_last_activity = datetime.now() - last_activity

                    print(f"User {request.user} last activity: {last_activity}")
                    print(f"Time since last activity: {time_since_last_activity}")

                    # Check if the user is inactive for more than 10 minutes
                    if time_since_last_activity > timedelta(minutes=10):
                        # Log out the user and consider them inactive
                        user_detail = UserDetail.objects.get(user=request.user)
                        if user_detail.isCurrentlyActive:
                            user_detail.isCurrentlyActive = False
                            user_detail.save()
                            print(f"User {user_detail.user} is now inactive and logged out.")
                        logout(request)
                        
                    else:
                        # Update the isCurrentlyActive field to True
                        user_detail = UserDetail.objects.get(user=request.user)
                        if not user_detail.isCurrentlyActive:
                            user_detail.isCurrentlyActive = True
                            user_detail.save()
                            print(f"User {user_detail.user} is still active.")
                else:
                    # Update the isCurrentlyActive field to True
                    user_detail = UserDetail.objects.get(user=request.user)
                    if not user_detail.isCurrentlyActive:
                        user_detail.isCurrentlyActive = True
                        user_detail.save()
                    print(f"User {user_detail.user} is now active.")

                # Update the last activity timestamp in the session
                request.session['last_activity'] = datetime.now().isoformat()
                print(f"User {request.user} last activity updated to {request.session['last_activity']}")

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

It is important to note that it is working, but only if I reload the page or send some sort of request.

I also have some inactivity code in my settings.py

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1800 # 30 minutes in seconds. "1209600(2 weeks)" by default 
SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 600

SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True # "False" by default
```

How can I make it so that the user is automatically logged out and my backend is automatically updated after 10 minutes of inactivity without a request or reload needed to be sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

Django won't do this by default, as it's really a request management system, so changes are tied to requests.

- There are scheduling applications such as redis or celery, but those are probably a
  little overkill for this situation. If these are already in place, though, you might be able to co-opt them.
- If you have access to the server, you could use a server chronjob
  running a [command script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) to tidy up user sessions,
- Or you could do it clientside using javascript. There's a module called [django-auto-logout](https://pypi.org/project/django-auto-logout/) will automate the clientside approach for you, and is probably the simplest way forward.

Let's say you use django_auto_logout and set up a redirect to the login page and a message "Session Timed Out: Please Log In Again"

In your login page view you could then do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages
...
request_messages = get_messages(request)
for message in request_messages:
    if message.message == "Session Timed Out: Please Log In Again":
           user_detail = UserDetail.objects.get(user=request.user)
           if user_detail.isCurrentlyActive:
               user_detail.isCurrentlyActive = False
               user_detail.save()
               print(f"User {user_detail.user} is now inactive and logged out.")
```

If you need more control your best bet might be to have a look at how the [module is written](https://github.com/bugov/django-auto-logout/tree/master/django_auto_logout) and adapt your own middleware to follow its approach.

Comment: Interesting, with django-auto-logout can I update the backend still? Like set the isCurrentlyActive to false?

Comment: ? just following up

Comment: You could conceivably by testing for the "timeout" message on, say, the login page view and then running whatever backend processes are necessary if it was present. Or just edit the middleware provided in the module - it's really only a middleware file and a context processor.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean? Could you please format your response as a answer so I could implement it?

Comment: Updated my answer with simplest approach code

Comment: I saw your answer and thank you for that. However, wouldn't it need some form of request from the user in order to update the backend? Also, you didn't show me how to implement the auto-log-out.

Comment: That is handled by installing the django-auto-logout module (where I said "Let's say you use django_auto_logout."). Follow the installation instructions for that module.  NB: It will still make an (automated) request to the server, as django by default only really processes requests.  To do it without requests you will need to go for one of the other options.