# Django - Automatically Log User Out & Update Backend After Inactivity WITHOUT Needing To Send Request

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am creating a simple multiplayer system in Django. Part of this system is that I want to automatically update the `isCurrentlyActive` value in a model assosiated with the user, and then log them out.

I implemented middleware as seen in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301938/django-inactivity-middleware-not-automatically-logging-user-out). This works perfectly, however, it requires the user to reload the page or make some sort of request to the server in order to update. This doesn't work for me, as I want the backend to automatically update the User's backend data and log them out WITHOUT them needing to send a request to the server.

Does anyone know how to do this? I saw implementations with `Celery` and `django-auto-logout` but they seemed too complicated and overkill.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Inactivity Middleware not automatically logging user out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301938/django-inactivity-middleware-not-automatically-logging-user-out)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way to handle this is through sessions as this is what they were designed for:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/

In theory you should just have to set the session expiry:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry

If you're doing this manually, the way http works, the only way to tell if someone is active is if a request was sent to the backend. This is why you need the middleware piece, as middleware is simply a wrapper around *any* request that gets sent. The middleware you would need would have to track the date/time of the last http request the user sent

In order to automatically expire from the back, you would need to write a scheduled task (Celery) to look at when they last sent a request, and if it is older than your max timeout then force the logout. As your number of users grow, however, you're going to find you're running a ton of scheduled tasks that heavily query the system for not much gain.

However, I do think sessions and session timeouts will cover what you're trying to do a lot more cleanly.

Comment: I have tried using sessions, but how can I update the backend with them?

Comment: The sessions will cover your logout scenarios. Then your middleware can track the last request sent by the user and isCurrentlyActive is just a date-time function doing a comparison between the last request sent and now(). If you need to track the "currently active" on a data model then you will have to create the celery task as described

Comment: Could you add that to your answer and provide me with the code? I checked out the links but they didn't seem to help.

Comment: If you want more insight into how session tracking works feel free to check out how I'm "crediting" page view time from middleware in this project:
https://github.com/helmetwearer/django-simple-web-course/blob/main/django_simple_web_course/core/middleware.py#L5

unfortunately the real reality is tracking an "active" status on the model isn't really a good idea... all you can track is the last request they sent to make a determination, and other frameworks will provide you the same limitation because that's just how HTTP works

Comment: If you find http too limiting because of this, perhaps you should instead look at managing connections directly through TCP:
https://realpython.com/python-sockets/