# How to call custom logout function automatically in Django WITHOUT needing to send a request

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, middleware

I have a custom `logout` function, which updates the `isCurrentlyActive` value in the user's backend and logs them out:

```
def logoutUser(request):
    try:
        user = request.user
        user_detail = UserDetail.objects.get(user = user) 
        user_detail.isCurrentlyActive = False # set users activity to false
        user_detail.save()
        logout(request)
        return redirect('home', )
    except:
        return redirect('home', )
```

I want to automatically log the user out after more than 10 minutes of inactivity. I implemented a custom middleware to do so, but this fails as a request such as a reload is needed in order for the function to be called.

I've experimented with backend processes such as `Celery` and `Redis` but they all are overkill and don't necessarily work.

I was wondering what the easiest way to accomplish this would be? I want to automatically call the custom logout function without the user needing to make a request to the server. Essentially, this should happen in the background.

Comment: *but this fails as a request such as a reload is needed in order for the function to be called.* - In order to logout user you've to send request from client side but if you don't want to reload page then you can send **AJAX** request to logout it from server side and can show popup to user that their session is expired please logIn.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, could you please format your comment as an answer using my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Inactivity Middleware not automatically logging user out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76301938/django-inactivity-middleware-not-automatically-logging-user-out)

Comment: No that was your answer which did not help.